# how to alert when changes in jexcel cells if user navigates using onbefoerunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, spreadsheet, onbeforeunload

I want to show a alert for changes made in jexcel cells.

I have a save button to save data. Now if user changes any cells I want to show a alert using `onbeforeunload` when navigating to other page.

```
var unsaved = false;

$(":input").change(function(){ //triggers change in all input fields including text type
    unsaved = true;
});

function unloadPage(){
    if(unsaved) {
        return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
```

This code will work only for input type. How to make it work for jexcel cells. I use jexcel v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach `onchange` event listener to your jexcel table, here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/t24bw1jf/) to demonstrate how to listen to change events on your cells, also here is code as a snippet (the snippet will not work since SO is sandbox which will not allow certain code to run, this snippet will work on your local machine if you test it out):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<script src="//bossanova.uk/jexcel/v4/jexcel.js"></script>
<script src="//bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//bossanova.uk/jexcel/v4/jexcel.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="spreadsheet"></div>
<div>
    <button onclick="$('#log').html('')">Clear</button><br>
    <p>Log:</p>
    <div id="log" style="background-color:#c7eaff; border-radius:2px; color:#000; padding:20px"></div>
</div>

<script>
var changed = function(instance, cell, x, y, value) {
    var cellName = jexcel.getColumnNameFromId([x,y]);
    $('#log').append('<p>New change on cell ' + cellName + ' to: ' + value + '</p>');
}

var data = [
    ['Mazda', 2001, 2000, '2006-01-01'],
    ['Pegeout', 2010, 5000, '2005-01-01'],
    ['Honda Fit', 2009, 3000, '2004-01-01'],
    ['Honda CRV', 2010, 6000, '2003-01-01'],
];

jexcel(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
    data:data,
    rowResize:true,
    columnDrag:true,
    columns: [
        { type: 'text', width:'200' },
        { type: 'text', width:'100' },
        { type: 'text', width:'100' },
        { type: 'calendar', width:'100' },
    ],
    onchange: changed
});
</script>
</html>
```

---

So you can simply have your unsaved variable/flag be changed inside `onchange` event listener, also this example is taken from the [official website](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v4/examples/events) where it have a list of events listeners attached to the jexcel table

Answer (score 1):

Jsuites is a dependency of jexcel and has already a plugin that enables that.

```
<form id='myForm'>
<input type='hidden' name='data'>
<div id='spreadsheet'></div>
<input type='button' value='Save data' onclick='saveData(); myTracker.resetTracker()'>
</form>

<script>
var myTracker = jSuites.tracker(document.getElementById('myForm'));

jexcel(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
    onafterchanges: function(el) {
        document.forms[0].name.value = el.jexcel.getData();
    }
}
</script>
```

So, basically you implement saveData to save your data and reset the tracker to start tracking the changes again.

One other change here is to start the formTracker only after you set the initial table content. So, if the user open a table don't perform any change, and leave won't alert since there was no change in the data.

Source: https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/tracking-for-form-changes